# CSS - add ellipsis without text-overflow

Tags: css

I am looking to add an ellipsis "..." at the end of the text inside a `<div>` Is this possible using CSS?

I am aware of `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but I am not looking to truncate the text. I just want to have "..." at the end of the text.

Comment: `p::after {content:"..."}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the ellipsis with an `after` pseudoelement

```css
.ellipsis::after {
  content : "\2026";
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">Text inside a div</div>
```

`U+2026` is the unicode for the orizontal ellipsis